# I need to get internet on my computer to my USB connected phone

Tags: laptop, usb, internet-connection, mobile-phone, hp-pavilion

My laptop has internet via Ethernet. I have connected a phone via USB which has no internet. So, is there any way I can get internet working on my phone via USB. The laptop is an HP Pavillion DV6. The phone is a Moto G (1st gen).

Note: My laptop doesn't have Wi-Fi capabilities for some reason. Only Bluetooth is working.

Note 2: I apologize for inconvenience if this information is incomplete.

Comment: So your laptop can't use Wi-fi and you wouldn't like to buy anything (eg. USB Wifi Adaptor, Wifi router, ...) is this right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this would work with your Moto G but an Android solution has been posted in the Android SE: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/73168/how-to-use-pcs-internet-on-android-phone-through-usb-cable. Not sure if this wouold work on your version of Moto G...

Alternatively, you could look at an **OTG USB-to-Ethernet** adapter which would then allow you to be able to plug your phone directly into your router via an Ethernet cable - if your router has a spare LAN socket.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

USB? well why not turn the [HP Pavilion into a hotspot](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Wireless-Internet-Home-Networking/turning-the-HP-Pavilion-dv7-into-a-hotspot/td-p/1593589)

Goto Network Connections and right-click on your wireless adapter and select Properties. Now goto the Wireless Network Tab and click on the Advanced button. Select Computer to Computer (Ad hoc) networking option. If you get a window with an SSID box, you can specify the network name in it, in our example we will use Wi-Fi as the SSID. Now close the window and click on Add Preferred Networks.

Enter the settings as follows:

Network name (SSID) : Wi-Fi
Network Authentication : Open
Data Encryption : Disabled

This is a computer-to-computer (ad hoc) network, wireless access points are not used” option if it isn’t already ticked. To automatically connect to the network, goto the Connection tab and tick on the Connect automatically when in range option. Now, to configure the TCP/IP connection settings, goto the General tab and select Internet Protocol (TCP/IP) and click the Properties button. Set the Values as:-

IP Address - 192.168.0.1
Subnet Mask - 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway - 192.168.0.2

5. Click OK and you have finished the steps

Comment: then open the Wireless network settings on your phone and click on View Available Wireless Networks. Select your network and you are connected.

Comment: well just usb is not set up for internet protocol

Comment: @Peter Hayek the laptop has internet via Ethernet not the phone.

Answer (score 0):

Here Is the Both Internet for USB or Wifi:

■Go to All apps(). 
 ■Tap to Settings
 ■Touch more and then go to Tethering & Mobile Hotspot.
 ■Touch Mobile Wi-Fi hotpot t enable the Moto G WiFi hotspot.

Customise Moto G Mobile Hotspot settings

■Touch to Set up Wi-Fi Hotspot.
 ■Enter or use the default Network SSID as per your wish.
 ■Choose the security type and Password.
 ■Touch Save.

You are done. Now you can use your Moto G as WiFi Hotspot.

Moto G USB tethering

■Connect your Moto G to PC
 ■Windows will automatically install the required drivers.
 ■Once this is done, follow above mentioned first 3 steps.
 ■Touch USB tethering

Now your PC will be connected to internet using Moto G as USB modem.

from http://smartphonetethering.blogspot.co.uk/2014/08/how-to-use-moto-g-as-modem-to-connect.html

Comment: Please read the question again. I don't have internet working on my phone. Without working internet on my phone, there is no point in turning into a hotspot.

Answer (score -2):

I know another way can share Internet from laptop to mobile phone. It is basd on WiFi hotspot in laptop. A small tool can help you create a WiFi hotspot in Windows computer for sharing. Know more here: [How to share Internet from Windows computer](http://goo.gl/VwJy76) for mobile phone. I think it is better than USB.

Comment: Reading the question specifically says the OP's laptop doesn't have wifi so they can't use the laptop as a portable hotspot... the OP seems to looking at turning the USB connection into an ethernet connection so that they can access the internet on the phone via USB through the laptop's existing ethernet connection.